# How to generate all possible combinations out of a given array

Tags: java, arrays, combinations

Since people got confused, I'm rewriting my question again with a code.

I want to make d here dynamic, i.e., I want to be able to generate all possible combinations of array values without knowing the value of d in advance.

Right now, I'm using if-clause and I can only support d from 1 to 4.

```
if( d == 4 )
{
        for( double i = min ; i <= max ; i = i+ sz )
        {
            for( double j = min ; j <= max ; j = j + sz )
            {
                for( double h = min ; h<=max ; h = h + sz )
                {
                    for( double p = min ; p<=max ; p = p + sz )
                    {
                        double[] att = {i, j, h, p};
                    }
                }
            }
        }
}

if( d == 3 )
{
    for( double i = min ; i <= max ; i = i+ sz )
    {
        for( double j = min ; j <= max ; j = j + sz )
        {
            for( double h = min ; h<=max ; h = h + sz )
            {   
                double[] att = {i, j, h};
            }
        }
    }   
}

if( d == 2 )
{
    for( double i = min ; i <= max ; i = i+ sz )
    {
        for( double j = min ; j <= max ; j = j + sz )
        {
            double[] att = {i, j};
        }
    }   
}

if( d == 1 )
{
    for( double i = min ; i <= max ; i = i+ sz )
    {
        double[] att = {i, j};
    }   
}
```

As you can see, if I don't know the value of d before, I won't be able to do it.

and one more thing, I don't want to use any template or predefined classes like List, etc.

Comment: I'm very confused by the question itself.

Comment: My advice: Do your own homework. The exercise was designed as a learning experience, but getting others to do it for you defeats that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this

```
static void moves(ArrayList<Integer> prefix, ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> result, int min, int max, int stepSize, int maxLength) {
  if(prefix.size() == maxLength) result.add(prefix);
  else {
    for(int i = min; i <= max; i += stepSize) {
      ArrayList<Integer> newPrefix = new ArrayList<Integer>(prefix);
      newPrefix.add(i);
      moves(newPrefix, result, min, max, stepSize, maxLength);
    }
  }
}

static ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> moves(int min, int max, int stepSize, int maxLength) {
  ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> result = new ArrayList<>();
  moves(new ArrayList<Integer>(), result, min, max, stepSize, maxLength);
  return result;
}
```

And then you can call it with e.g. `moves(0, 50, 5, 2);`

Comment: so how to use the output from the moves function? why it is nested ArrayList? shouldn't it be a simple list like: ArrayList<Integer> ?

Comment: Your code works fine, but I'm not sure how could I convert the nested ArrayList to just a simple ArrayList? I mean, how to convert ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> to ArrayList<Integer> ?

Comment: Could you please tell us how to convert ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> --------> ArrayList<Integer> ???

Comment: I thought you wanted all combinations and not just one. How can you represent more than one combination with only one ArrayList<Integer>?

Answer (score 1):

Here's the piece of code that does what you want:

```
private static int[][] getPossibleValues(final int[] from, final int[] to, final int step) {
    final int width = from.length;
    final int[][] values = new int[width][];

    for (int idx = 0; idx < width; idx++) {
        values[idx] = makeSequence(from[idx], to[idx], step);
    }

    return values;
}

@SuppressWarnings("boxing")
private static List<Integer[]> getPossibleCombinations(final int[][] values, final Stack<Integer> fixed) {
    final int width = fixed.size();
    if (width == values.length) {
        // System.out.println(fixed);
        return Collections.singletonList(fixed.toArray(new Integer[0]));
    }

    final List<Integer[]> res = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < values[width].length; i++) {
        fixed.push(values[width][i]);
        res.addAll(getPossibleCombinations(values, fixed));
        fixed.pop();
    }

    return res;
}

private static int[] makeSequence(final int from, final int to, final int step) {
    if (((to < from) && (step > 0)) || ((to > from) && (step < 0))) {
        return new int[] { from };
    }

    final int len = ((to - from) / step) + 1;
    final int[] res = new int[len];

    int cur = from;
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        res[i] = cur;
        cur += step;
    }

    return res;
}
```

You can use it as follows:

```
public static void main(final String[] args) {
    final int[] from = new int[] { 0, 0, 0 };
    final int[] to = new int[] { 1, 1, 1 };
    final int step = 1;

    for (final Integer[] ints : getPossibleCombinations(getPossibleValues(from, to, step), new Stack<Integer>())) {
        System.out.println(Arrays.asList(ints));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
[0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 1]
[0, 1, 0]
[0, 1, 1]
[1, 0, 0]
[1, 0, 1]
[1, 1, 0]
[1, 1, 1]
```

---

Bonus, checking whether the arguments are sensible:

```
@SuppressWarnings("boxing")
private static void checkArgs(final List<Integer> init, final List<Integer> target, final int step) {
    if (init.size() != target.size()) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Initial and target arrays must be of the same size.");
    }

    if (step == 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("The step shouldn't be 0.");
    }

    final boolean increment = step > 0;
    for (int idx = 0; idx < init.size(); idx++) {
        if ((increment && (target.get(idx) < init.get(idx))) || (!increment && (target.get(idx) > init.get(idx)))) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                                                String
                                                    .format(
                                                            "Inconsistent arguments for elements at the index %s: %s cannot reach %s with increments of %s.",
                                                            idx,
                                                            init.get(idx),
                                                            target.get(idx),
                                                            step));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like there has been a misunderstanding.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this is a great thinking problem that took me a while to get my head around.
Going to be tough to guide you through it without giving an answer.

Generally people would ask "What code have you tried?". You should be able to write some code that does the permutations for one value of the array and then work your way from there.

Starting with some code.

```
perm(int[] start, int step, int[] max, int[] min)
```

Is this what the method signature should look like? You have an array that you start from. How far you 'jump' for each step and each index of the array has a max and min value that needs to be accounted for.

I started off by creating a `int[] copy` of the starting array. We need to copy the original values back when we increment the next index value.

It's easy enough to increment the first element in the array. `copy[0] += step;`. Now we need to do some checking. If that value is greater than max or less than the min, we need to reset that value (`copy[position] = start[position];`) and increment the next index by the step.
Then you will notice some code that loops in terms of logic. We also need to check the value we incremented is within it's bounds. So it is a matter of writing that code in a loop that keeps account of the position in the array that it is working on.

Start with small blocks of code that do what you need, work your way up to progressing through the array and dealing with the edge cases (when it goes over max, goes over min, when you have finished processing the array).

Happy to answer further questions but you'll need to ask specific ones with examples of code you have so I don't feel like I'm writing the code for you.

Answer (score 0):

The following attempts to generalize the idea of nested loops:

```
static int[][] permute(int[] initial, int[]min,int[] max,int step){//input parameters
    int dim = initial.length;                     //assume all arrays are equal, should probably check though
    int[] start = new int[dim];                   //array for storing the starting value of each loop
    for (int i = 0; i < dim; i++) {
        start[i] = min[i]+(initial[i]-min[i])%step;//finds the smallest value within the given bounds
    }
    int[] steps = new int[dim];                   //number of iterations of each loop
    int totalElements=1;                          //total elments in result
    for (int i = 0; i < dim; i++) {
        steps[i] = (max[i]-start[i])/step+1;      //computes the number of steps in each dimension on [min,max] inclusive
        totalElements*=steps[i];
    }

    int[][] results = new int[totalElements][];//for storing results
    for (int i = 0; i < totalElements; i++) {
        results[i]= new int[dim];
        int temp = i;
        for (int j = 0; j < dim; j++) {
            results[i][j] = start[j] + ((temp%steps[j]) * step);//clever method for looping through the array sand storing the result
            temp/=steps[j];
        }
    }
    return results;
}
```

running

```
int[][] result = permute(new int[]{10,5}, new int[]{0,0}, new int[]{50,50}, 5);
for (int[] i : result)
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(i));
```

produces:

```
[0, 0]
[5, 0]
[10, 0]
[15, 0]
[20, 0]
[25, 0]
[30, 0]
[35, 0]
[40, 0]
[45, 0]
[50, 0]
[0, 5]
[5, 5]
[10, 5]
[15, 5]
[20, 5]
[25, 5]
[30, 5]
[35, 5]
[40, 5]
[45, 5]
[50, 5]
[0, 10]
[5, 10]
[10, 10]
[15, 10]
[20, 10]
[25, 10]
[30, 10]
[35, 10]
[40, 10]
[45, 10]
[50, 10]
[0, 15]
[5, 15]
[10, 15]
[15, 15]
[20, 15]
[25, 15]
[30, 15]
[35, 15]
[40, 15]
[45, 15]
[50, 15]
[0, 20]
[5, 20]
[10, 20]
[15, 20]
[20, 20]
[25, 20]
[30, 20]
[35, 20]
[40, 20]
[45, 20]
[50, 20]
[0, 25]
[5, 25]
[10, 25]
[15, 25]
[20, 25]
[25, 25]
[30, 25]
[35, 25]
[40, 25]
[45, 25]
[50, 25]
[0, 30]
[5, 30]
[10, 30]
[15, 30]
[20, 30]
[25, 30]
[30, 30]
[35, 30]
[40, 30]
[45, 30]
[50, 30]
[0, 35]
[5, 35]
[10, 35]
[15, 35]
[20, 35]
[25, 35]
[30, 35]
[35, 35]
[40, 35]
[45, 35]
[50, 35]
[0, 40]
[5, 40]
[10, 40]
[15, 40]
[20, 40]
[25, 40]
[30, 40]
[35, 40]
[40, 40]
[45, 40]
[50, 40]
[0, 45]
[5, 45]
[10, 45]
[15, 45]
[20, 45]
[25, 45]
[30, 45]
[35, 45]
[40, 45]
[45, 45]
[50, 45]
[0, 50]
[5, 50]
[10, 50]
[15, 50]
[20, 50]
[25, 50]
[30, 50]
[35, 50]
[40, 50]
[45, 50]
[50, 50]
```

Comment: Could you please take a second look at the question, I added a code and more explanation. thanks.

Comment: @user1728624 what are the input parameters to the function and their types supposed to be?